# SSI - Can view in dreamweaver but not on ther server

Tags: server-side-includes

I have a line of code that I am unable to view. I am using a spry nav bar.  I am saving the files  as navigation.shtm, and the file that it is going is is products.shtm

This is a simple link and it should be working fine but I can get it to work correctly.

```
  <div id="column1">
  <div class="menu">
  <div>
            <!--#include file="ssifooter/navigation.shtm" -->
  </div>
  </div>       
  </div>
```

The data file is (Dreamweaver spry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What server are you running?

**Windows**

- For IIS 6.0 check out this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/eced0b89-e052-42ff-baa8-751dd191c3b5.mspx?mfr=true).
- For IIS 7.0 there is an option within the OS you need to install (Windows 7 under Application Development Features of the Internet Information Services options of turning on or off windows features)

**Apache**

Check out this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/ssi.html) for how to configure and install the extension

Comment: I believe it is an Apache server.